# Does Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 contain any spoilers for Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

I've waited to buy Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 because I didn't know if it contained any spoilers for the new Dragon Ball Super show.

**Are there any Dragon Ball Super spoilers in Xenoverse 2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly? It kinda depends on what would be a spoiler.

If we look at the [story arcs of super](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_sagas#Dragon_Ball_Super) the story in the base game of Xenoverse 2 touches on things from the God of Destruction and Resurrection F stories, which the show has adapted from the movies with minor changes.

The season pass (DLC) expanded content for the game so far (DB Super Pack 1&2) seems to draw from the Universe 6 arc.

Answer (score -2):

Only Toriyama can give you an answer on that, and maybe  not even he be able to do so: both for marketing rights etc, i.e. meaning the production regardless of the original author can extend the show - as it happened before with DB GT for example - or merely by tori himself, remember Z to super has almost 3 decades, 30 years gap.

Comment: Super is only 5 years after Z. Buu is unsealed and defeated in the year 774, and Pan is born, along with Freiza's Resurrection, in 779. Goten and Trunks are still children in Super as well. Even then, Toriyama gave the manga and anime a basic list of major events which they do what they want in order to execute. This is why the Manga was ahead but fell behind the Anime, yet almost every major events is still the same, so a lot more people than just Toriyama knows